# sending websocket messages from my dockerized backend to my dockerized frontend

Tags: python, django, docker, websocket

I'm sending websocket messages from an external script to a django page  and it works fine until i dockerize it.
my django page (my frontend) is running on port 80, and my frontends docker-compose states

```
    ports:
      - 80:80
    hostname: frontend
```

and my backend.py file is trying to connect with this line

```
async with websockets.connect('ws://frontend:80/ws/endpoint/chat/', ping_interval=None) as websocket:
```

so i think my backend should be able to see it.

its able to connect when not dockerized with

```
async with websockets.connect('ws://localhost:80/ws/endpoint/chat/', ping_interval=None) as websocket:
```

the error i get when dockerized is

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "//./main.py", line 531, in send_SMS_caller
    asyncio.run(SendSMS())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 647, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "//./main.py", line 496, in SendSMS
    async with websockets.connect('ws://frontend:80/ws/endpoint/chat/', ping_interval=None) as websocket:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/websockets/legacy/client.py", line 637, in __aenter__
    return await self
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/websockets/legacy/client.py", line 655, in __await_impl_timeout__
    return await self.__await_impl__()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/websockets/legacy/client.py", line 662, in __await_impl__
    await protocol.handshake(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/websockets/legacy/client.py", line 329, in handshake
    raise InvalidStatusCode(status_code, response_headers)
websockets.exceptions.InvalidStatusCode: server rejected WebSocket connection: HTTP 404
```

chatgpt suggested i point to the specific ip of my hostmachine which i do like

```
async with websockets.connect('ws://3.46.222.156:80/ws/endpoint/chat/', ping_interval=None) as websocket:
```

but i basically get the same error.

what do i need to do to send websocket messages from my dockerized backend to my dockerized frontend?